# hasManyThrough intermediate Model based relationship?

Tags: php, eloquent

I have 3 tables: `Role`,`ThreadPermission`, and `Thread`. Their table structure is as follows:

```
Role
  - id
  - name
ThreadPermission
  - id
  - role_id
  - thread_id
  - is_Moderator (bool)
Thread
  - id
  - title
```

Here's a screenshot of `ThreadPermission` data:

[image]

I am actually having a hard time explaining the relationship (that's why the edits)

So, when I create a new `Thread` object, I also create a new `ThreadPermission` object where I assign `is_Moderator` attribute to each `Role`, as hopefully you can see in the screenshot above

I wish to access `Thread` via `Role` method where `is_Moderator` equals `TRUE` in `ThreadPermission`. There's 2 problem that seems I need to solve, first building the relationship between `Role` to `Thread`, the second one is to only show `Thread` at which `is_Moderator == TRUE` in `ThreadPermission`

To handle the first problem I tried implementing this in my Role Class:

```
class Role extends Eloquent {

    public function moderatedThreads() {
        // Hopefully I can also 'ThreadPermission'->where('is_Moderator', TRUE)
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Thread', 'ThreadPermission', 'role_id', 'id')->get();
    }

}
```

but when I try to `var_dump` the method:

```
var_dump($app->user->roles()->moderatedThreads());
```

it returns an empty object

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#203 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I am so confused as to which part of implementation did I mess up. Do you guys can see what I can't see?

Comment: Have you tried this code in class Role:
'return $this->hasManyThrough('Thread', 'ThreadPermission', 'role_id', 'id')->toSql()'?
That might help you to see what is wrong with query.

Comment: @Grommy thank you very much, because of that my issue can only be solved by hacking Eloquent http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many/?page=1